# HTML form using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to retrieve data from server using jQuery AJAX on HTML form then store the response data in a php string variable. So far my code is:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" id="myform" action="https://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe">
<input name="exec" value="viewproduct" type="hidden">
<input name="customer" value="customer_name" type="hidden">
<input name="sku" value="sku_number" type="hidden">
<input name="submit" type="button">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#myform").submit(function(e){
    var postData = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = jQuery(this).attr("action");
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
       url : formURL,
       type: "POST",
       data : postData,
       success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
       {
         jQuery('#results').html(data.toString());
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
         alert('fail');    
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#myform").submit();
});
</script>
```

But I still haven't see any result. If I just use the form normally without any js code, then I'll get the raw response data from the server/database directly on the browser. How can I save that raw response data on the browser into a string variable in php?

Comment: You're not getting the fail alert, right? If #results is remaining blank, either it's not visible, or your php isn't returning anything.

Comment: *"How can I save that raw response data on the browser into a string variable in php?"* doesn't make sense. can you please clarify?

Comment: sorry what I meant to lead to was that there's no data in the form being submitted

Comment: I'd actually bet that his form is following through with the actual action URL before the data returns from the AJAX call.  It won't wait for that to finish if he doesn't `e.preventDefault()` first.

Comment: I did get the alert fail. I've tried to add the preventDefault, but still get no response. Again, if I use the bare form only, then I do get response from the server/database. My concern is, how can I capture that raw data into a variable before it's shown up on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `submit()` handler to include this in the first line:

```
jQuery("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //  <---
    ....
```

and/or add `return false;` to the end of it.

If that stops it from reloading but doesn't show anything in your `#results` div, troubleshoot by changing your `success()` in the AJAX to use this:

```
jQuery('#results').html(data.toString());
```

If that shows something, go to your server code and split up your data into individual properties that your Javascript can separate and use individually (or combine it all into one big string if you want).

`.html()` takes an input of String, not an object (which `data` is in this case).

Comment: Thanks, but it still return "fail".

Comment: That's good.  It means your server code is what you need to worry about now.  You can post that too if you want help with it

Comment: Wish I could, but the remote server/database is not even using PHP. The server does send response in http response format (if I use regular form). I need to capture that response into a file or a variable to be parsed.

Comment: Instead of `alert('fail')` you can do `console.log(jqXHR);` and also `console.log(textStatus);` and `console.log(errorThrown);` and view the results in your console to see what the root of the issue is

Comment: Thank you. I got this error: "NetworkError: 400 CONTENT_TYPE!=appli...n/x-www-form-urlencoded - https://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe"

Comment: try adding `dataType: html` right after `data: postData` and then see what error comes up.

Comment: Unfortunately, now I got ReferenceError: html is not defined error. If I put dataType: 'html', I got the same error as before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45681/discussion-between-deryck-and-user1576748)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to store the Javascript value into a PHP variable because PHP runs on the server and returns a response to the browser where Javascript runs on the browser. What you could do is call your script with AJAX and then set your form values with jQuery using

```
$("input[name=customer]").val(data);
```

You could either have an AJAX call for each input or you could parse out the return string to get each value. The first may be more straight forward.

If the action is becoming an issue, remove the  entirely and just add an onClick to the submit button that calls a function that makes the AJAX calls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I run the above codes in a PHP file. I'm trying to capture the HTTP Response data that are sent by the server after submitting the 3 values in the form.